# How to spit Ecto Migrations into partials?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I have many migration files using the same column names `name`, `address`, `phone`, etc.

In my migrations, I want to make a partial that calls them instead of writing it over and over:

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.CreateUsers do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:settings) do
      add :blah, :string
      App.Repo.Migrations.Common.stuff



defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.Common do

  def stuff do 
    add :name, :string
    add :address, :string
    add :phone, :string
```

But I get an error (UndefinedFunctionError) function App.Repo.Migrations.Common.stuff/0 is undefined.stuff

What's the proper way to split migrations? In Rails this was done with `require_relative`

Answer (score 0):

I can guess you put the file `common.ex` inside `priv/repo/migration` which is not included while compilation

for this to work you need 2 things:

1. move this file `common.ex` inside `lib/`, in order to be compiled and loaded.
2. add this line `use Ecto.Migration` above `def stuff do`, for the definition of `add()` to be imported.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function, just like [`timestamps/1`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/v3.8.3/lib/ecto/migration.ex#L1036) :

```
def timestamps(opts \\ []) when is_list(opts) do
    opts = Keyword.merge(Runner.repo_config(:migration_timestamps, []), opts)
    opts = Keyword.put_new(opts, :null, false)

    {type, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :type, :naive_datetime)
    {inserted_at, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :inserted_at, :inserted_at)
    {updated_at, opts} = Keyword.pop(opts, :updated_at, :updated_at)

    if inserted_at != false, do: add(inserted_at, type, opts)
    if updated_at != false, do: add(updated_at, type, opts)
  end
```